# How to save file Uri in Sharedpreferences and set in MediaPlayer

Tags: android, kotlin, file, uri

**I want to get the Uri of a file through select files. When I receive it, I save it in SharedPrefences as a string**

```
val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
            uri?.let { edit.putString("customtimersound", it.toString()).apply() } }

resultLauncher.launch("audio/*")
```

**but when I want to get it to play it causes an error**

```
call.setDataSource(this@MainActivity, SettingsActivity.uri(this@MainActivity)
```

(**the SettingsActivity.uri()**)

```
fun uri(context: Context): Uri {
            val settings: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            return Uri.parse(settings.getString("customtimersound", ""))
    }
```

**Error**                                                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException

**I think I'm spelling Uri wrong in SharedPrefences**
**Или неправильно указал context**

Comment: You will get a  `content` `Uri`, not a `file` `Uri`. You will need to switch to `OpenDocument` from `GetContent`, and use `takePersistableUriPermissions()` to get durable access to the content. See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) for more.

Comment: @CommonsWare can be more? did not quite understand what to do and how to do it